# Optimize ajax synchronously calls

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have some ajax script that fire off about 250 synchronous PHP calls . This is my script

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
      $("#generate").html("<div class='modal'><p>Initializing...</p></div>");
      $.ajax({
          url:'/fetch around 250 url from database.php',
          async:false,
          dataType: 'json',        
          success: function(data){      
               $.each(data,function(key,val){
                    $("#generate").html("<div class='modal'><p>Fetching "+val.url+"</p></div>");
                    saveimage(val.url); 
              }
              $("#generate").html("<div class='modal'><p>done</p></div>");    
                    finalcreate();
          },
     });
   });
   function saveimage(){
        $.ajax({
             url: 'do some php work.php',
             async: false,
        });
    }
    function finalcreate(){
        $.ajax({
             url: 'do some php work.php',
             async: false,
         });
    }
```

In the first part script fetch more than 250 urls from database and for every url script do some php calculation using another ajax call. when the loop ends script do final ajax call.

When i run this programe in firefox, it run successfully for only 40 urls, then browser shows dialog box with option of whether user want to stop this script or not, if user want to run this script then the script run again for next 40 urls , same proccess occure till the end.
How i can optimize this script, i dont want browser show option to stop this script. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: If they're synchronous, you can't do anything. It's a browser thing. Why do you need them synchronous?

Comment: Your ajax isn't *a*jax.  I'd consider rewriting this to actually handle your urls asynchronously.  Better yet, implement some batch processing on your php end so you don't need to make so many http requests in the first place.

Comment: @jadkik94 i want synchronous only to show progress of script to the user end. If i used asynchronous request then before completing the loop, the script call "finalcreate()" function. How can i manage these things i want to call finalcreate method only after saveimage() function. Any Idea ..??

Comment: @JayC the fetching the url from database doesn't take too much time,actual time consuming thing is saveimage call, if i fetch url from http request then call ajax request to save image, then i think i got the same problem.

Comment: @Arjun Jain: You're getting the script timeout precisely because you're firing these requests synchronously.  Ajax requests can be chained together in various ways, which would avoid the issue entirely, as asynchronous requests would allow the user interface to still be responsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function nextrequest() {
    if (requests.length == 0) {
        $("#generate").html("<div class='modal'><p>done</p></div>");
        finalcreate();
        return;
    }
    var val = requests.pop();
    $("#generate").html("<div class='modal'><p>Fetching "+val.url+"</p></div>");
    saveimage(val.url);
}
var requests = [];
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#generate").html("<div class='modal'><p>Initializing...</p></div>");
  $.ajax({
      url:'/fetch around 250 url from database.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){
        requests = data;
           nextrequest();
      },
 });
});
function saveimage(){
    $.ajax({
         url: 'do some php work.php',
         success: function(data) {
            // do something...
            nextrequest();
         }
    });
}
function finalcreate(){
    $.ajax({
         url: 'do some php work.php',
     });
}
```

You store all the URLs in a global variable, and everytime a request is done, you get the next one, until all of them are consumed, `(requests.length == 0)`, you call the final request.

This way the user can still do something else on the page, and you can display progress everytime a request is done. Also, a good thing is that you can make 2 calls at once, or more, to make the process faster.

Comment: Thanks a lot jadkik94. Now the script run very fast as compared to previous.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax call needs much time to complete, as it communicates with remote server. The slowest thing there is a query to the server. You should send one batch request with all data needed to the server, that should separate the data and handle it. Everything should be completed about 250 times faster.

Answer (score 0):

make some time interval for each ajax request

```
 success: function(data){      
                   $.each(data,function(key,val){
                        $("#generate").html("<div class='modal'><p>Fetching "+val.url+"</p></div>");
                        setTimeout(saveimage(val.url),3000); 

                  }
```